# How to get the AccessToken in Facebook.Client v0.9.91-alpha

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm trying to publish to a user's feed, and I've got Login working using the facebook.net SDK.  I've installed both the Facebook and Facebook.Client nuget packages.

This line of code isn't working for me:

```
var fbClient = new Facebook.FacebookClient(_loginButton.CurrentSession.AccessToken);
```

Specifically, `.CurrentSession` does not exist as a property on the LoginButton class.  Without it, I can't get the `AccessToken`, and can't publish to a user's wall.

What's the right way to do this in Facebook.Client 0.9.91-alpha?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some trial and error, I believe I've found the answer.  The `AccessToken` is now accessible via `Session.ActiveSession.CurrentAccessTokenData.AccessToken`, which means the line of code should be:

```
var token = Session.ActiveSession.CurrentAccessTokenData.AccessToken;
var fbClient = new Facebook.FacebookClient(token);
```